# Best way to join this query

Tags: mysql, performance

I have the following tables and data:

```
Tables
-----------
CREATE TABLE primarys 
( primaryid BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (primaryid));

CREATE TABLE patients
( primaryid BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
patientid BIGINT(20),
patientName VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY (primaryid));

CREATE TABLE patientvisit
( primaryid BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
visitid BIGINT(20),
visitdate DATE,
PRIMARY KEY (primaryid));

Data
---------
INSERT INTO primarys values (1);
INSERT INTO primarys values (7286);
INSERT INTO primarys values (7287);

INSERT INTO patients VALUES (1,'1','John');
INSERT INTO patients VALUES (7286,'1', '');
INSERT INTO patients VALUES (7287,'1', '');

INSERT INTO patientvisit VALUES (7286,'1','1997-12-18');
INSERT INTO patientvisit VALUES (7287,'2','1998-02-25');
```

I need to write a query that outputs the data as follows:

```
primaryid   |  patientid    |   patientname    |  visit   |  visitdate
------------------------------------------------ 
7286        |   1           |  John            |   1      |  1997-12-18
7287        |   1           |  John            |   2      |  1998-02-25
```

I can figure out how to do this with outer joins and sub queries which work fine but when I start adding a large data set mysql performance begins to significantly decrease.

I would be very grateful if anyone could suggest the most optimised way to query these data and get the desired output.

Thanks

Comment: You can try index the key columns.

Comment: How does the table `questions_1_100` relates to the other tow tables? By which column?

Comment: Indexes would help, but it concerns me that you mention sub queries as with my guess as to how those tables join together no sub query would be required. And if you are using a correlated sub query then that might also explain the poor performance.

Comment: Hi thanks for your replies. The base of this query was discussed in another thread: stackoverflow.com/questions/16237669/mysql-join-very-slow i thought i would start a new thread as this was a separate part of the original question

Comment: I agree the table structure doesnt make much sense. Essentially q_1 is an ID column - for example patientID.... q_4 is also another id question... for example patient visit... a patient can have multiple visits.... i know ideally they tables would be structured correctly however this is a loose structure with the primary table having the key value pairs. Hope that makes sense

Comment: My apologies it wasnt clear how the rows linked together. They are in fact linked by the primary id. I have updated the data to show that questions_1_100 in fact also have the same primary ID as in questions_101_200. I suppose the issue i am having here is q_2 as this one is contained in a row with a different id... however it is a value relating to q_1 (patient id).... in fact im going to update the column names to help us see it more clearly

Comment: OK ive updated the column names for readability. I know the structure of the database is not ideal but of course this is a structure i have to work with right now and cant change it for the time being. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

For the specific values you display in your question, this query would do.

```
SELECT q2.primaryid, q_1, q_2, q_4, q_5 FROM questions_101_200 q2
CROSS JOIN questions_1_100
```

But your data and structure doesn't make much sense to me. If you explain more about what you are trying to do, I can give you a more meaningful answer.

Comment: Wow!!! Marjeta, the cross join appeared to do it. I have never even seen this before. I will be looking into this straight away!!! Many thanks!

Comment: Actually it works in this example but when there are multiple subjects and multiple visits then no longer works.

Comment: Thanks Marjeta, please see more information in other answer above.